# How to implement update controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am working on web app development using ruby on rails. I want to enable users to upload images for their favorite food. I have food_item model and a food_image model. In the food_item model:

```
has_many :food_images
has_many :food_portions ＃this is the work done by another teammate
```

I also define in the food_item controller:

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_items).permit(:name, :category, :description, food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, :avatar]).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:portion] = params[:food_items][:portion]
  whitelisted[:price] = params[:food_items][:price]
end
```

Comment: Why are you saving, without changing anything? you just queried it by find.

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff this method renders a form for user to upload an image, if the user click save, then the image will be saved in the database. I defined in show.html.haml to present the image on webpage.

Comment: post your view and your 'rake routes' please

Comment: @dthal Hi I already posted my view and routes

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

1. You need to save your updated object
2. You *should* be doing this within the bounds of *resources* (although not essential)

---

[**Resourceful**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

The first step is to ensure you're using this with the correct routes etc.

You shouldn't have an `add_images` method in your controller - you could achieve what you need with `edit`/`update`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :food_items do
    resources :images #-> if necessary, this should be its own controller rather than adding needless methods to your other controller
end
```

You should use the following controller setup:

```
#app/models/food_item.rb
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_images
end

#app/controllers/food_items_controller.rb
class FoodItemsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @food_item = FoodItem.find params[:id]
      @food_item.food_images.build
   end

   def update
      @food_item = FootItem.find params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
        if @food_item.update food_item_params
           ...
        end
      end
   end

   private

   def food_item_params
     params.require(:food_items).permit(:name, :category, :description, food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, :avatar]) #-> this is enough (no need to "whitelist")
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to load the following:

```
#url.com/food_items/:id/edit
#app/views/food_items/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @food_item do |f| %>
= form_for @food_item, html: { :multipart => true } do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
 = f.fields_for :food_images do |p|
     = p.label :avatar
     = p.file_field :avatar
.actions
   = f.submit
<% end %>
```

This will submit to the "update" method, which should save the required object for you.

**You should only upload one file at a time**

If you need to upload multiple files, you'll need to use a gem such as `cocoon` to add them. Rails is great but not magical -- it has to build a single object with each `fields_for`.

I can explain more about this if required.

--

To give you context on why you should be using the `edit` / `update` methods for this, you need to look up the *resourceful* principle for object orientated programming.

[image]

This is built on the "resources" principle put forward at the [inception of HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource) -- a standardized set of technologies which allow browsers to send and retrieve data from servers.

In short, it means there are certain [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) you should abide by to keep your app extensible.

Because Ruby/Rails is [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), everything you do in a well-tailored application should revolve around *objects*. Like resources, these allow you to create a system which is both flexible and extensible *if* done properly.

Thus, with your code, you have to remember that you're trying to *add an image* to the *food items* object. You should therefore be `editing` the food items object, *updating* it with the extra image; which the above code will help you achieve.

Comment: Hi @Rich Peck, I have followed your answer. I have deleted the routes and controller method for adding images. I put a form in edit.html.haml and this will call the update method to save the object. However, the update method has been implemented by my teams and it is difficult for me to add code to it to avoiding broken current tests. I will put the update method in my question.

Comment: Okay looking forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

Like Badheka said: "why are you querying and just saving the @food_item?

Anyways, Notice that when you try to create food_images, you did:

```
food_item_params[:food_image]['avatar'].each do |a|
   @food_image = @food_item.food_images.create!(:avatar=>a)
end
```

You were looping through the `avatar` in `food_image` attributes of `food_item_params`

However, if you check your `food_item_params`, you have:

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_items).permit(food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, :avatar])
end
```

With this, in all possibility, the structure of the data that this params is expecting will be something like:

```
{
  food_items: 
    {
      food_images_attributes:
        {
          id: "",
          food_item_id: "",
          avatar: ""
        }
    }
}
```

while what is being returned by your `food_item_params` will be as follow:

```
{
      food_images_attributes:
        {
          id: "",
          food_item_id: "",
          avatar: ""
        }
    }
```

There are a number of issues with this:

1) The error you are getting: `param is missing or the value is empty: food_items` this suggests that the param that is coming in is not in the format specified above. the parent attribute `food_items` is missing, so that is the first part of your code that you need to rectify from inside the view where you are sending the avatar, or conform your `food_item_params` method to meet the structure of what is coming in through the params.

2) There is no `food_item_params[:food_image]['avatar']` to loop on, since thee is no `food_image` in your params. What you have is `food_image_attributes`, so your loop will be on `food_item_params[:food_image_attributes][:avatar]`

3) Looping through the `food_item_params[:food_image_attributes][:avatar]` suggests that it is an array. If so, then the way you are permitting it is wrong too. You will have to specify that it is an array from inside the `food_item_params` method as follow:

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_items).permit(food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, avatar: []])
end
```

If however, as I suspect, what is coming through your param is as follow:

```
food_images_attributes:
        {
          id: "",
          food_item_id: "",
          avatar: []
        }
```

Then your `food_item_params` method should be as follows:

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_images_attributes).permit(:id, :food_item_id, avatar: [])
end
```

I'll advise you check your params and paste what it looks like here.

And as a last word, check what you are sending from the view, and set your controller accordingly, or check what you want the controller to expect, and send same from the view.

Comment: I already took your advice. When I define  `food_item_params` like

Comment: Hi @SunnyK, I already took your advice. I loop on `food_item_params[:food_image_attributes][avatar]`.  However, when I defined  `food_item_params` like you did in the last, I got the error `param is missing or the value is empty: food_images_attributes`  when running cucumber. When I kept the same way and used `avatar:[]`, I got the same error `param is missing or the value is empty: food_items` again.

Comment: Can you show me what is coming in through your params? [You can either use a pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry/versions/0.10.3), or copy it directly from the console terminal of your server

Answer (score 0):

You need to change food_item_params method :

From :

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_items).permit(food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, :avatar])
end
```

To :

```
def food_item_params
  params.require(:food_item).permit(food_images_attributes: [:id, :food_item_id, :avatar])
end
```

Also, you can improve your code :

Add accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_images in food_item model, then make changes in controller's method

```
def add_image
  @food_item = FoodItem.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
      if @food_item.update_attributes(food_item_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @food_item, notice: 'Images uploaded successfully' }
      else
         format.html { redirect_to add_image_food_item_path}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried what you did, but changing :food_items to singular will ruin other functionality. Also in the add_image method, it is not creating image objects to hold the file I uploaded through the form.

Comment: Have you added accepts_nested_attributes_for in model?